# detail of leader retry when follower fail in raft

Tags: consensus, raft

I have read the [paper](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) about raft, and I am confused with

> If followers crash or run slowly, or if network packets are lost, the
> leader retries AppendEntries RPCs indefinitely (even after it has
> responded to the client) until all followers eventually store all log
> entries.

which is written at the beginning of the section `5.3 Log replication`.

To make my confusion more clear, I split it into two questions.

---

**Question 1. Should leader retry in all of three failure situations below?**

1. reply false if term < currentTerm (in Figure 2)
2. reply false if log doesn’t contain an entry at prevLogIndex whose term matches prevLogTerm (in Figure 2)
3. rpc error or timeout

---

**Question 2. If leader should retry in some situation, does the leader process will block until all followers reply success?**

---

Below is my attempt:

- In first failure case, there is no need that leader should retry.
- In second failure case, leader should retry, and adjust the nextIndex of the follower until the follower replies success. Also leader will be blocked before accepting next client request.
- In third failure case, there is no need that leader should retry, and we can append the failure entry at next client request.

Answer (score 2):

The quote only describes the leader will retry when the follower doesn't give a response for whatever reason (e.g. follower issue or network issue).

In scenarios 1 and 2 you listed under Question 1, followers do give a rejection response to the leader, so that's different from your initial confusion.
Now to answer what will happen in these scenarios:

1. If the leader's current term X < the follower's current term Y, the leader step down to follower mode because there must be another leader for term Y.
2. The follower rejects AppendEntries RPC because the follower doesn't contain logs at the prev index. In that case, the leader should force the follower to duplicate the leader's logs before appending new entries. The mechanism is described in Handling of inconsistency section.

The answer to Question 2 is very simple: The leader can proceed and update the state machine when the majority has returned success. Retrying on the remaining followers is for data consistency purposes, it doesn't slow down the system.